# Passing a 2d array to a thread

Tags: arrays, multithreading, pthreads, multidimensional-array

I'm new to the concept of threads and am trying to understand them a bit better. I'm aware that to create a thread and send a 2d array to it, would look something like this:

```
pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, ProcessArray, threadArray);
```

But I'm struggling to understand what would then happen in ProcessArray. How would the array be read or understood to be made usable by the ProcessArray function?
As I said I'm new to threads so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threads use the same memory, so threadArray exists in any of your threads, and you can access them. You may need mutex to protect the variables against concurrency problems.

If you had used the function `fork`, the memory would not be shared.

You speak about '2darray', be careful, don't use `your_type threadArray[n][m]`, but `**threadArray`: your thread function has the prototype `void *ProcessArray(void *data)` and you have to convert `data` to `your_type **threadArray`, and it's not the same that threadArray[n][m] => you may get a segfault.